# BigQuery connector for Microsoft Excel. Bad parameter

Tags: google-bigquery

I try to connect to Google BigQuery by Excel. I generated key which is recognized by connector IQY as bad parameter. I guess my key is too long. I revoked key and created a new one but problem still exists.
My parameters attached on pic. [My_key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdqBc.png)
Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: this is not really a question could you rephrase

Comment: Pls extend the question, adding some more input in order to support here.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any advice appreciated.